# Adding HTML by javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
<title>untitled</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="Geany 0.21" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = aaa;
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.innerHTML ='adadsdsfd';
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="aa">
        ddgdf
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to append a simple html element by javascript but it is not working can someone please point out what is wrong.

Comment: `aaa` in `divIdName` is treated as a variable, but I don't see it defined anywhere. Maybe you wanted `"aaa"`(a string)?

Comment: If you look in the error console of your browser, you're likely to see an error saying `aaa` is undefined.

Comment: Besides `aaa` being undefined you try to access `document.body` before it's available. Move the script to the end of your document.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: aaa is not defined is the error.... change it to "aaa"... Your code works then. http://jsfiddle.net/3Exb6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
var divIdName = aaa;
```

to

```
var divIdName = 'aaa';
```

as `aaa` does not look like a variable, it should be string, and add you script before `body` closing , like

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'aaa';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.innerHTML ='adadsdsfd';
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
</script>
</body>
```

as `document.body` wont be available to you script placed inside `head` at the time the script gets executed

Answer (score 2):

Your `id` string is not properly quoted -

```
var divIdName = "aaa";
```

JavaScript considers `aaa` as a variable name.

Also, you should move your `script` to the end of the document. See @pawel's comment.

Final code -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>untitled</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 0.21" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="aa">
        ddgdf
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div'),
            divIdName = 'aaa';

        newdiv.setAttribute('id', divIdName);
        newdiv.innerHTML ='adadsdsfd';
        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```